# Priority Queue synchronization with pthreads

Tags: c, multithreading, synchronization, pthreads

I'm working on a college assignment where we are to implement parallelized A* search for a [15 puzzle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/15_puzzle). For this part, we are to use only one priority queue (I suppose to see that the contention by multiple threads would limit speedup). A problem I am facing is properly synchronizing popping the next "candidate" from the priority queue.

I tried the following:

```
while(1) {
  // The board I'm trying to pop.
  Board current_board;

  pthread_mutex_lock(&priority_queue_lock);
  // If the heap is empty, wait till another thread adds new candidates.
  if (pq->heap_size == 0)
  {
    printf("Waiting...\n");
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&priority_queue_lock);
    continue;
  }
  current_board = top(pq);
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&priority_queue_lock);

  // Generate the new boards from the current one and add to the heap...
}
```

I've tried different variants of the same idea, but for some reason there are occasions where the threads get stuck on "Waiting". The code works fine serially (or with two threads), so that leads me to believe this is the offending part of the code. I can post the entire thing if necessary. I feel like it's an issue with my understanding of the mutex lock though. Thanks in advance for help.

Edit:
I've added the full code for the parallel thread below:

```
// h and p are global pointers initialized in main()
void* parallelThread(void* arg)
{
    int thread_id = (int)(long long)(arg);
    while(1)
    {
        Board current_board;

        pthread_mutex_lock(&priority_queue_lock);
        current_board = top(p);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&priority_queue_lock);

        // Move blank up.
        if (current_board.blank_x > 0)
        {
            int newpos = current_board.blank_x - 1;
            Board new_board = current_board;
            new_board.board[current_board.blank_x][current_board.blank_y] = new_board.board[newpos][current_board.blank_y];
            new_board.board[newpos][current_board.blank_y] = BLANK;
            new_board.blank_x = newpos;

            new_board.goodness = get_goodness(new_board.board);
            new_board.turncount++;

            if (check_solved(new_board))
            {
                printf("Solved in %d turns",new_board.turncount);
                exit(0);
            }

            if (!exists(h,new_board))
            {
                insert(h,new_board);
                push(p,new_board);
            }
        }

        // Move blank down.
        if (current_board.blank_x < 3)
        {
            int newpos = current_board.blank_x + 1;
            Board new_board = current_board;
            new_board.board[current_board.blank_x][current_board.blank_y] = new_board.board[newpos][current_board.blank_y];
            new_board.board[newpos][current_board.blank_y] = BLANK;
            new_board.blank_x = newpos;

            new_board.goodness = get_goodness(new_board.board);
            new_board.turncount++;

            if (check_solved(new_board))
            {
                printf("Solved in %d turns",new_board.turncount);
                exit(0);
            }

            if (!exists(h,new_board))
            {
                insert(h,new_board);
                push(p,new_board);
            }
        }

        // Move blank right.
        if (current_board.blank_y < 3)
        {
            int newpos = current_board.blank_y + 1;
            Board new_board = current_board;
            new_board.board[current_board.blank_x][current_board.blank_y] = new_board.board[current_board.blank_x][newpos];
            new_board.board[current_board.blank_x][newpos] = BLANK;
            new_board.blank_y = newpos;

            new_board.goodness = get_goodness(new_board.board);
            new_board.turncount++;

            if (check_solved(new_board))
            {
                printf("Solved in %d turns",new_board.turncount);
                exit(0);
            }

            if (!exists(h,new_board))
            {
                insert(h,new_board);
                push(p,new_board);
            }
        }

        // Move blank left.
        if (current_board.blank_y > 0)
        {
            int newpos = current_board.blank_y - 1;
            Board new_board = current_board;
            new_board.board[current_board.blank_x][current_board.blank_y] = new_board.board[current_board.blank_x][newpos];
            new_board.board[current_board.blank_x][newpos] = BLANK;
            new_board.blank_y = newpos;

            new_board.goodness = get_goodness(new_board.board);
            new_board.turncount++;

            if (check_solved(new_board))
            {
                printf("Solved in %d turns",new_board.turncount);
                exit(0);
            }

            if (!exists(h,new_board))
            {
                insert(h,new_board);
                push(p,new_board);
            }
        }
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the code that manipulate the queue, if this code is small (otherwise, can you provide a simpler version)? It helps use [to reproduce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) the problem.

Comment: I've added all the code for the parallel threads (it's mostly code for moving the tiles and generating a new board, and pushes into it). I can include the code for the code for the priority queue and Hash Map if that would help. Not sure I can reduce it further without losing context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried the following:

I don't see anything wrong with the code that follows, assuming that `top` also removes the board from the queue. It's wasteful (if the queue is empty, it will spin locking and unlocking the mutex), but not wrong.

> I've added the full code

This is useless without the code for `exists`, `insert` and `push`.

One general observation:

```
    pthread_mutex_lock(&priority_queue_lock);
    current_board = top(p);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&priority_queue_lock);
```

In the code above, your locking is "ouside" of the `top` function. But here:

```
        if (!exists(h,new_board))
        {
            insert(h,new_board);
            push(p,new_board);
        }
```

you either do no locking at all (in which case that's a bug), or you do locking "inside" `exists`, `insert` and `push`.

You should not mix "inside" and "outside" locking. Pick one or the other and stick with it.

If you in fact do not lock the queue inside `exists`, `insert`, etc. then you have a data race and are thinking of mutexes incorrectly: they protect *invariants*, and you can't check whether the queue is empty *in parallel* with another thread executing "remove top element" -- these operations require serialization, and thus must both be done under a lock.

Comment: You're right, it was a mistake and misunderstanding about locks on my part, it's now fixed and I have locks for all the accesses. What is the advised approach besides "spin locking"?

Comment: @Favre To avoid spinning in lock / unlock, use a condition variable.